# Print dataframe after grouping H2o python

Tags: python, pandas, h2o

**Data:** "https://github.com/estimate/pandas-exercises/blob/master/baby-names2.csv"
In pandas:

```
df=pd.read_csv("baby-names2.csv")
df_group=df.groupby("year")
print df_group.head()
```

It prints the dataframe grouped by year.
**How do I do the same thing in H2o Python ?**
In H2o:

```
df=h2o.upload_file("baby-names2.csv")
df_group=df.group_by("year")
print df_group.head() ==> gives Error
```

Expected output: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrS1V.png

Answer (score 0):

To get an h2o frame after you've used `groupby()`, use `.get_frame()` which returns the result of the group-by. For example, if you wanted to get the count for each year you could do:

```
df=h2o.import_file("baby-names2.csv")
df_group=df.group_by("year").count()
df_group.get_frame()
```

[which prints the year and count columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3iCX.png).

Comment: are you just looking for a way to sort your data?

Comment: yes. I just want to organize my data based on year. same as the one i have attahed